# what causes sd-encrypt to reset my terminal resolution?

Tags: systemd, disk-encryption

using systemd's bootd with this list of hooks defined in `mkinitcpio.conf`

```
HOOKS=(base systemd autodetect modconf kms block keyboard sd-vconsole sd-encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)
```

and

```
 $ cat /boot/loader/loader.conf 
console-mode keep
```

and no custom font or resolution anywhere.

My boot goes fine until the sd-encrypt prompt. Everything renders OK (even if i'm using a custom vconsole font, or a custom kernel fb font, none of which i'm using for these screenshots) then...

[image: boot going ok]

one second later (no matter if i'm typing my password right away or just waiting) it will reset my terminal to 1/4 of the screen size.

[image: bam. quarter resolution]

Don't be fooled by the first line being the password prompt. It depends on the font size and the size of the "screen" that it will revert to. If the font is larger, it will show more left over text.

Also notice how the cursor is still in the old position.

any idea what is causing this?

Comment: How do you know *sd-encrypt* is resetting the resolution? In other words, how do you know sd-encrypt is the _only thing running_ at that time?

Comment: It's a best guess. I did move the sd-encrypt hook order around and tried to remove all others. I also assume there's nothing else being loaded since my root is encrypted. so it is pretty much the only thing left in my initrd. If there is something else, it is not present in any term/serial/log output either. Also, tried to add custom fonts/looks to all term related things to see where they load, and they all happens before that prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a combination of the `kms` hook and `sd-encrypt`.

no matter if it was placed before or after each other.  or kms is before after `sd-console`. The resolution/mode will always reset while waiting for the sd-encrypt prompt. I don't have the means to debug it, but since my hardware doesn't require `kms` (e.g. digital privacy screen laptops), i 'fixed' by removing it from the list.